# Why Enumerable.SequenceEqual throws exception if any parameter is null?

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x,y)` as I expected it to work based on 
`Object.Equals(x,y)` method, which returns false if x or y is null, and true if both are null (for null cases).

However `Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x,y)` throws exception if any parameter is a null reference and will not return true if it is given two nulls.

In my code I check for collection equality quite often so I created a method that mimics `Object.Equals` behaviour for sequences but I just wonder whats the logic behind such default behaviour, and is there maybe an existing method with no exceptions on nulls?

Comment: Well, the fact that the first parameter being `null` throws an exception, makes sense, since it is an extension method. It is typically invoked as `x.SequenceEqual(y)` and thus mimics `x.Equals(y)`, which would also throw if `x` where `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) explicitly states that it throws an `ArgumentNullException` in case any one of the passed in sequences is null. I assume it's to keep consistency with "standard behaviour" where an object throws a `NullReferenceException` when you try to dereference it. Consider this:

```
 List<int> foo = null;
 foo.SequenceEqual(new List<int>());
```

This would be ok as `SequenceEqual` is an extension method and therefore can handle a null object but it would also be confusing. Every extension method provided by Linq follows this behaviour as far as I know. Also you don't need to handle special null cases for every extension method (you would need to agree about sensible behaviour and add additional logic and maintain and test it). Saying that it is illegal makes it more robust (against logic bugs) and consistent from a framework perspective. I use Linq a lot and never ran into that problem - I just make sure all my sequences are not null. Reduces code clutter a lot (removes lots of null checks from the code).

Answer (score 4):

The point at which it is checking for sequence equality is not when that exception is being thrown. It is being thrown earlier as an argument validator. Consider the method:

```
public static bool SequenceEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

We explicitly need to check that `source` and `target` are not null, because if any of them are, then we **can't** check for sequence equality. This is an unworkable state, and the result of `SequenceEquals` should be governed by the contents of the enumerables, not the state of the enumerables. If it were to include the latter, when returning `false`, how would the caller know whether it is actually failing because the sequences are not equal, or whether one or both of the enumerables are `null`?

If we didn't thrown an `ArgumentNullException` here, the CLR would thrown a `NullReferenceException` when you try and access one of the `null` enumerables. Simply saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is a lot less helpful then `The argument <something> cannot be null`.

Remember, the type of exception thrown is typically one of the most helpful indicators about *why* an exception was thrown.